# computing bounding box of union of two boxes

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres and trying to use the geometric types.  I don't have a good source for the basic geometric manipulations.  For example, the bounding box of two bounding boxes.  I wrote code, which I hope is correct, but it's ugly.

Would appreciate help making it pretty (and more correct).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION containingBox( bx1 Box ,  bx2 Box ) returns Box AS $cB$
       DECLARE
        minX  double precision;
        minY  double precision;
        maxX  double precision;
        maxY  double precision;
        bx Box;
       BEGIN
       if bx2 is null then
          return bx1;
       else 
          if bx1 is null then
             return bx2;
       end if;
       minX := least( (center(bx1))[0]-.5*width(bx1), (center(bx2))[0]-.5*width(bx2));
       maxX := greatest( (center(bx1))[0]+.5*width(bx1), (center(bx2))[0]+.5*width(bx2));
       minY := least( ((center(bx1))[1]-.5*height(bx1)), ((center(bx2))[1]-.5*height(bx2)));
       maxY := greatest( (center(bx1))[1]+.5*height(bx1), (center(bx2))[1]+.5*height(bx2));
       bx:=box(point(minX,minY),point(maxX,maxY));
       return bx;
       END;
$cB$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: For starters, the second if does not need to be inside an else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) installed, right?

You can use the built-in functions in that case. Don't think you need a stored procedure at all.

```
SELECT ST_Extent(thegeom) FROM
    (SELECT bx1 as thegeom
    UNION
    SELECT bx2 as thegeom) as geomlist;
```